# Каким правилом объяснить запятую (→)?

Tags: пунктуация

> «Так что же это за окрестности?!» – в страхе пропустить что-нибудь
>   очень важное, теребила я нашего провожатого, смущая его молчаливое
>   достоинство.

После "в страхе пропустить что-нибудь очень важное"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*«Так что же это за окрестности?!» – **в страхе пропустить что-нибудь очень важное** теребила я нашего провожатого, смущая его молчаливое достоинство.*

Думаю, что запятая не нужна. Это факультативное обособление обстоятельства, актуализация его причинного значения.

Но в данном случае оборот лучше не обособлять: предложение и так уже имеет обособленный деепричастный оборот, куда больше.